# Are the convergent sequences dense in the bounded sequences?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

Since it would be comfortable for something I am currently trying to prove if this would hold I wanted to ask here whether it is true that $c$ is dense in $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,\cdots)=(0,1,0,1,\cdots)$. Suppose that there is a convergente sequence $x_n$ such that $$|x_n-y_n|\leq \epsilon \tag{1}$$

where $\epsilon$ is  small number. We conclude from $(1)$ that $x_{2n+1}$ is close to $0$ while $x_{2n}$ is close to $1$. This implies that $$|x_{2n+1}-x_{2n}|\ge 1+\delta$$

for some positive small $\delta$ depending on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Which convergent sequence is close to the sequence whose $n$-th term is $(-1)^n?$

Answer (score 3):

$c$ is closed in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$!